# How to compare form elements with strings in an if statment

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having allot of trouble with this and I've tried many different ways to do this and I just ran out of ideas.

Here's my code:

```
var user = document.Log.User;
var pass = document.Log.Pass;

function Login (){
if(user.value == "Admin"){
window.open();
}
}
```

Here Is the HTML side:

```
<form name="Log">
        <input class="Log" type="text" name="User">
    <input class="Log" type="password" name="Pass">
    <input type="button" value="Login" name="But" onclick="Login()" style="width: 70px;position: relative;left: 150px;top: -25px;">
</form>
```

Comment: Is the Javascript before or after the body?

Answer (score 1):

use id Selector an put your variable assignments inside **Login** function:

**HTML :**

```
<form name="Log">
    <input id="User" class="Log" type="text" name="User">
    <input id="Pass" class="Log" type="password" name="Pass">
    <input type="button" value="Login" name="But" onclick="Login()" style="width: 70px;position: relative;left: 150px;top: -25px;">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function Login (){
    var user = document.getElementById("User");
    var pass = document.getElementById("Pass");

    if(user.value == "Admin"){
        window.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that will make a difference? The old style of accessing form elements still works.

Comment: And what about `document.getElementByName('User')[0]`?  Also, you spelled `Element` wrong

Answer (score 1):

If your variable assignments are in Javascript that's loaded before the body, then the elements that they refer to don't exist yet, and you should be getting errors. There are a number of ways to fix this:

1. Put the Javascript in the body somewhere after the form.
2. Put the Javascript inside `window.onload=function() { ... }`.
3. Assign the variables inside the `Login()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing this kind of login logic stuff with js, but, this would work:

```
function Login (){
  var user = document.querySelector('form[name=Log] [name=User]');
  var pass = document.querySelector('form[name=Log] [name=Pass]');

  if(user.value == "Admin"){
     window.open("yoururl.com");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers